# if loop inside if loop

Tags: android, if-statement

Here is the code I am having problem with.

```
if (ADi == 1) {
     if (RS >= 10)
         System.out.println("oooooooo");
         {      // TODO codes incomplete

            System.out.println("ohhhhh");
            vib2.vibrate(600);
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
            R.raw.beep02);
            mp.start();
        }
        finish();
       }
```

The problem is it don’t check `RS>=10` its simply play the mp and vibrate . `RS = 0` . I am not getting this out put "ooooooo" I am getting "ohhhhh" . I don’t want to play mp and vibrate if `RS < 10` .

Any help is much appreciated .

Comment: remove this `System.out.println("oooooooo");` put that in a else

Comment: when should it play and vibrate on what condition

Comment: @Raghunandan According to the Questioner's code, `System.out.println("oooooooo");` should be executed, if `System.out.println("ohhhhh");`, but not executing it. Why?

Comment: @VenomVendor `I don’t want to play mp and vibrate if RS > 0`. so if `RS>=10` its till >0 so it should not play and vibrate

Comment: @Raghunandan ok, which also means it should not execute `ohhhhh`. But this is not the case. Is the OP wrong?

Comment: @VenomVendor its not clear on what condition op wants to vibrate

Comment: @Raghunandan This is not about vibration or playing, this is about execution. If `ohhhhh` is printed, which means that `oooooooo` should be printed even before that. Now read the question once again.
`I am not getting this output "ooooooo" I am getting "ohhhhh"`

Comment: it was RS < 10. my last edit did not save

Comment: @VenomVendor i read it. op wants to vibrate based on some condition not vibrate an play on some condition which is not clear. is not getting `oooooooo` or `ohhhh..` its just a log message. the part is when to play and vibrate when not to

Comment: removing System.out.println("oooooooo"); fixed it guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i m not wrong you are committing a very silly mistake...

```
if (ADi == 1) 
{
      System.out.println("oooooooo");
      if (RS >= 10)
      {      
        System.out.println("ohhhhh");
        vib2.vibrate(600);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
        R.raw.beep02);
        mp.start();
      }
      else
        finish();
}
```

If you compare your code the only thing i did was to move `System.out.println("oooooooo");`
above  `if(RS>=10)` since you said `System.out.println("oooooooo");` is printing it means your RS is working but you are consuming it by printing that "ooooo" . `System.out.println ()` is also a statement and line of code .And since your RS is consumed hence the  code including Mediaplayer are called independantly of RS condition.

Btw i think you should be calling finish in else

Hope it helps... thx

Comment: i did not know this System.out.println("oooooooo"); make this much problem ..huuu. let me try all this

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "else"!  It helps if you format your code in a more readable way:

```
if (ADi == 1)
{
    if (RS < 10)
    {
        System.out.println("oooooooo");
    }
    else
    {      // TODO codes incomplete
        System.out.println("ohhhhh");
        vib2.vibrate(600);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
        R.raw.beep02);
        mp.start();
    }
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
if (ADi == 1)
{
    if (RS >= 10)
    {      
        System.out.println("ohhhhh");
        vib2.vibrate(600);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
        R.raw.beep02);
        mp.start();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("oooooooo");
    }
    finish();
}
```